# jquery scroll top on css3 tabs

Tags: jquery, css, animation, tabs, scroll

I'm using these `tabs` but when I click on tabs it produce a rapid `top scroll effect`.

Trying to use below script by changing id's but still not working:

http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/pure-css-tab-with-fade-animation/

```
jQuery("#button").click(function() {

    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a JavaScript-error and the tab just links to # thus resulting in a scroll to top.

Answer (score 0):

The rapid scrolltop effect is due to the default  action, which is to give focus to the associated , in that case the concerned checkbox which is placed like this:

```
position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
```

Because of the focus, it goes right back on top of the page.  There are a few ways you could change this. Either you choose NOT to work with labels and checkbox and you add instead an active class (since you are already using jquery anyways...)  `[id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content] {`} -> `.active tab-content { }`

So on click you would add "active" class on the selected LI or whatever and change CSS appropriatly.

Else you could preventDefault the default action and then RECREATE IT without the top scrolling effect, pretty much like this:

```
$('.tabs').on('click','label', function(e) { 
e.preventDefault() 
// Shouldn't need to UNCHECK the other ones since its a radio button
$(this).siblings('input').attr('checked','checked').trigger('click');
})
```

Or, and this is what i suggest most, you HIDE the input radios but not the way it's hidden now.  You could opacity: 0, display: none or something like that, so that the offset is correct, not -9999px over top.

Hope this helped!